# prestashop error 302 during creation of category via webservice

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, crud, http-status-code-302

Good day.

i'm adding a category on prestashop, via webservice.
i've faced some a 302 error, and so I have tryed to start from scratch.

this is the file I have taken from the doc website as example of inserting a category:

```
<html><head><title>CRUD - Create Categories</title></head><body>
<?php
// Here we define constants /!\ You need to replace this parameters
define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://www.myserver.com');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'THEAUTHKEYISHERE');
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

// Here we use the WebService to get the schema of "customers" resource
try
{
    $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
    $opt = array('resource' => 'categories');
    if (isset($_GET['Create']))
        $xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/categories?schema=blank'));
    else
        $xml = $webService->get($opt);
    $resources = $xml->children()->children();
}
catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e)
{
    // Here we are dealing with errors
    $trace = $e->getTrace();
    if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
    else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
    else echo 'Other error';
}

if (count($_POST) > 0)
{
// Here we have XML before update, lets update XML
    foreach ($resources as $nodeKey => $node)
    {
        $resources->$nodeKey = $_POST[$nodeKey];
    }
    try
    {
        $opt = array('resource' => 'categories');
        if ($_GET['Create'] == 'Creating')
        {
            $opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
            $xml = $webService->add($opt);
            echo "Successfully added.";
        }
    }
    catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex)
    {
        // Here we are dealing with errors
        $trace = $ex->getTrace();
        if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
        else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
        else echo 'Other error<br />'.$ex->getMessage();
    }
}

// We set the Title
echo '<h1>Categories\'s ';
if (isset($_GET['Create'])) echo 'Creation';
else echo 'List';
echo '</h1>';

// We set a link to go back to list if we are in creation
if (isset($_GET['Create']))
    echo '<a href="?">Return to the list</a>';

if (!isset($_GET['Create']))
    echo '<input type="button" onClick="document.location.href=\'?Create\'" value="Create">';
else
    echo '<form method="POST" action="?Create=Creating">';

echo '<table border="5">';
if (isset($resources))
{

    echo '<tr>';
    if (count($_GET) == 0)
    {
        echo '<th>Id</th></tr>';

        foreach ($resources as $resource)
        {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$resource->attributes().'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '</tr>';
        foreach ($resources as $key => $resource)
        {
            echo '<tr><th>'.$key;
            if ((bool)$resource['required'] == true)
                echo ' (*)'; // * for required fields
            echo '</th><td>';
            if (isset($_GET['Create']))
                echo '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value=""/>';
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    }

}
echo '</table><br/>';

if (isset($_GET['Create']))
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Create"></form>';

?>
</body></html>
```

the error is the same:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2014 22:32:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze18
location: http://myserver.com/api/categories?filter%5Bname%5D=%5Bcategoria+test%5D?url=categories&filter%5Bname%5D=%5Bcategoria+test%5D
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

url rewrite is on, and the category blank schema is avialable at the blank schema url.

any idea of this strange 302 error (status)?

UPDATE 2/11/2014
i've digging some more, I have read about the 302 status, so i manage to have the "location:" parameteter from the 302 status, wich is a urlencoded URL.
if I use that url "as is" prestashop the webservice will not respond as it should, but if idecode the url, and check it, all is nice, the category i was searching is there, here the examples :

```
http://myserver.com/api/categories?filter[name]=[iPods]
```

this seems to work. while :

```
http://myserver.com/api/categories?filter%5Bname%5D=%5B+iPods+%5D?url=categories&filter%5Bname%5D=%5B+iPods+%5D
```

does not work, but this is the url that the webservice give back to me... anyone has some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved. the problem was that i had put on the

```
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://www.myserver.com');
```

but looking at the response, they come from

```
http://myserver.com/api/categories?filter%5Bname%5D=%5Bcategoria+test%5D?url=categories&filter%5Bname%5D=%5Bcategoria+test%5D
```

I only needed to delete that "www" in the define. **that's all**.

the problem was that htaccess try to make a redirection, a 302 one, but the component tthat read the xml doesn't support it.

Comment: Nice! was super confused at why it was tanking... works great!

Answer (score 0):

302 means "Found".  That's good - not an error.  Maybe I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: oh... it should be founded, but no response is given, i usually get an xml as response, not this "302 state". I consider it an error due to the fact that the example itself stops suddenly, without any other message (or action such as the creation of the category)

Comment: Make sure that the script you are trying to pull stuff from is actually returning something.  Try running the URL directly in your browser and see if stuff is being sent back.

Comment: i have turned on the error reporting:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PrestaShopWebserviceException' with message 'This call to PrestaShop Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:302'
this seems an error.

Comment: you were right, the 302 was not an error, but the component isn't smart enough to make the call on the redirect url... thanks anyway :)